# How to draw on the zoomed screen without locking screen?

Tags: windows, zoom

With the feature LiveZoom of ZoomIt. You can zoom in screen and you can still work on the Windows. But LiveZoom does not support the drawing mode.

Are there any other alternative programs to lets you draw on the zoomed screen without locking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check out the article [Zoom in Computer Screen on Windows and Live Drawing on It](http://www.presentation-assistant.com/resources/zoom-in-computer-screen-on-windows.htm). You may get the answer.

Comment: Could you perhaps post more details on this? We prefer to avoid just linking articles.

Comment: ZoomIt copy the screen as a picture and allows you to drawing.
But [Presentation Pointer](http://www.presentation-assistant.com/ppointer/) allows you to draw on “live” screen without lock it. You can draw on screen and still use its usual utilities, such as the buttons, commands, context menus, etc. Also Presentation Pointer provides LiveZoom and it supports Live Draw.